# My AR app is crashing after transfer to TargetSDKVersion 29

Tags: android, augmented-reality, sceneform

My AR app is crashing after transfer to TargetSDKVersion 29

Here is code base

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/15htBIZ2OFrHvsetri7PILlG9fujN3iyt?usp=sharing

we are using .sfa and .sfb file .

is it related to library using?

thanks,
Swarup

Answer (score 0):

.sfa and .sfb are deprecated since 1.15 try using GLB or GLTF

try moving on to   [open source version](https://github.com/ThomasGorisse/sceneform-android-sdk) of sceneform